# use openfiledialog to get path of open database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, openfiledialog

I'm using Visual Studio Expess 2010. I am trying to figure out how to use the openfiledialog to getthe path of my database.

Currently I close the connection to my database and then try to select the database in the open file dialog but Windows tells me: "This file is in use, close the file..."

If I've closed my db connection what else do I need to do to completely close the file so I can select it in the openfiledialog?

Comment: How are you closing the connection?

Comment: SQLcl.cn.Close(); <---- SQLcl is a class I built to store my connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the connection doesn't leave the `Stream` created to the file. `Dispose` the object you are using to set up the connection.

Comment: Should I just dispose the SQLConnection Object?

Comment: I used the dispose statement on my SQLConnection object and nothing happened. Windows still told me my file was open.

Comment: No, you need to dispose all objects that are using SQLserver in anyway. because they are connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend a lot on where the db file is, e.g. is it in your project? is it in your sql server data folder?

Try the following sql to give you the path if it's in the data folder...

```
select physical_name
from sys.database_files
where type = 0
```

if it's in the app_data folder of your project try a simple

```
Server.mappath
```

EDIT: If you insist on using the dialogue then try the following:

```
openFileDialog.ValidateNames = false;
```

See [this MS bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/738067/system-windows-forms-openfiledialog-validatenames)

"First: The dialog ALWAYS checks for invalid characters, even if ValidateNames is FALSE.

Second: if TRUE, dialog tries to open the file and warns if locked"

EDIT 2: To understand exactly why the database is still in use - [taken from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ad750bc-5987-4eb8-bd86-9e045b10d546/open-file-dialog-says-that-the-file-is-open-but-i-have-close-the-sqlconnection)

"The sqlservr.exe process that is started is kept running for a while after the last connection to the instance is closed. Therefore, it doesn't need to be restarted if another connection is opened. The length of time it stays around is set by the sp_configure option "user instance timeout". By default, this is set to 60 minutes but you can use thesp_configure command to change this."

Comment: The DB file is currently in my project.

Comment: I want to get the path using the openfiledialog specifically. I want it to be easy for end users who might be most comfortable doing it with the openfiledialog. The DB file is a local C# Service-based database dataset

Comment: Ok check new code, you could allways use one of my first suggestions to point the file dialog towards the right location I guess.